# Why do we use "car + by" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

From [The Killing](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637727) (TV_series) :

> Can I help you, sir?
>       Yeah, you can help me. 
>       My name's Stan Larsen.
>       Detective Holder promised to
>       send a car by to watch my house

I understand that completely, but my question is why ***"car by"*** ? Why do we use **by** in here ? Why don't we just say **car**?

other section :

> You said you'd send a car by.
>       My kids are terrified.
>       What-- what the hell are you
>       people doing about it?

Comment: A car will drive by the house.  The car was sent by the detective.  Thus: the detective sent a car by the house.

Comment: so is it formal or informal ?

Comment: "By" in this sense means "near" or "passing adjacent to".  Probably the simplest way to parse it is that the object of "by" is elided:  '... promised to send a car *by my location* to watch my house."

Comment: If I send a car, the comes to give you a ride somewhere. If I send a car by, you don't get in. The car is there for other purposes.

Comment: @Yosef: No. There's nothing wrong with, for example, [*(We'll) **send a car by** to pick (you up)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22send+a+car+by+to+pick%22) It's a mistake to interpret ***by*** there as meaning *passing **near**, but not actually stopping* (or more exotic variants such as the implication *in the area for some **other** reason*).

Comment: @Hot Licks: Idiomatically, there are many "prepositions of movement/location" that could replace ***by*** in OP's cited context. Most native speakers would be perfectly happy with ***[a]round, over, across, along, up, down, back,*** etc. in either that *exact* context or similar ones. I suppose ***back*** would of necessity have to imply something along the lines of ***returning***, but as with *He lives up/down the road*, I'm not sure you can always say ***up/down*** there really have much "meaning" (they certainly don't *necessarily* allude to any literal change in "elevation").

Answer (score 1):

The word by can also be used as an adverb to mean "at or to someone's home".

So it means ."Detective Holder promised to send a car at/to my house  to watch it".

Comment: Correct.  Based on context, the car is not "passing by" but instead "stationed at", since one cannot "pass by" and "keep watch".

Answer (score 0):

The word 'by' in this context suggests that the car is going to drive past (or by) the house rather than stopping at it.

Answer (score 0):

> Detective Holder promised to send a car by to watch my house

can be read as

> Detective Holder promised to send a car that will pass by my house and keep watch.

Comment: How can something that passes by, keep watch?  It would reason that after you pass by, you are no longer keeping watch.

Comment: OP's post most probably means "send the car to my house". But police can also provide security by just patrolling in general area around the house, letting everyone know that police is nearby. It all comes down to the context and how much security is needed.